# $L^p$ norm of multivariate standard normal random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Given $X_i\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ what is the behaviour of 
$$ ||X||_{l^p}=(\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|^p )^{1/p}$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$?
For $p=2$ results about $\chi$-distribution tell us that 
$$\mathbb{P}(||X||_{l^2}\le 2n^\frac{1}{2} )\rightarrow 1.$$

I am interested in analgous statments for $p\ne1$,i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}(||X||_{l^p}\le Cn^{e(p)} ),$$
where $C$ is allowed to depend on $p$.

Comment: Are $X_i$ independent?

Comment: The case $p=1$ is the easiest :)

Answer (score 2):

By the law of large numbers for i.i.d. random variables,
$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|^p\to E[|X_1|^p],
$$
almost surely, hence
$$
\frac1{n^{1/p}}\|X\|_p\to E[|X_1|^p]^{1/p},
$$
almost surely. In particular, for every positive $x$,
$$
P[(1-x)n^{1/p}E[|X_1|^p]^{1/p}\leqslant\|X\|_p\leqslant(1+x)n^{1/p}E[|X_1|^p]^{1/p}]\to1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assuming $X_i$'s are independent you can apply the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) on $$\frac{1}{n}\left\Vert X\right\Vert_{\ell^p}^p=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\lvert X_i\rvert ^p.$$